# Count lines of each text file in a folder parallel using fork() in C

Tags: c, unix, parallel-processing, synchronization, fork

I'm trying to complete a code for an assignment . The task is to create a program that counts the lines of each text file in the folder that the code runs in parallel way . So here's my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include "error.c"

char *getFileNameExtension(char *);
int isTxtFile(struct dirent *);
int countLines(struct dirent *);

int main(int argc , char *argv[]){

    //Current Directory
    DIR *currentDir;

    //Current File
    struct dirent *currDirFile;

    pid_t pid;

    int counter = 0;

    /*
    Struct stat "buf" variable , we'll need it
    to check the selected file's st_mode(file type)
    */
    struct stat buf;

    int *lines = malloc(sizeof(int));

    //Opens the directory where the executable exists with the dot(.)
    currentDir = opendir(".");

    if (currentDir){


      /*In the while loop we read each file
      of the current directory until we get a Nullable value */
      while( ( currDirFile = readdir(currentDir) ) != NULL ){

            if ( isTxtFile(currDirFile) == 1 ){

                if ((pid=fork())<0){
                    err_sys("fork error");
                }

                //Child
                else if(pid == 0){

                    exit(0);
                }
                //Father
                else{

                    lines = realloc( lines , sizeof(int)*(counter+1) );
                    lines[counter] = countLines(currDirFile);
                    ++counter;

                }
            }
        if (pid==0){
            printf("Child , pid = %d\n",pid);
        }
        else printf ("Father , pid = %d\n",pid);

      }//End while

      //close(currentDir);

    }

    int i ;

    for(i=0;i<counter;++i){
        printf("%d\n",lines[i]);
    }

    exit(1);
}

 char *getFileNameExtension(char *filename){
    //Gets the memory location of the last dot(.)
    char *ext = strrchr(filename, '.');
    return ext;
}

int isTxtFile(struct dirent *currDirFile){

         struct stat buf;

         /*With the lstat function we try to pass
         the current file into the buf variable*/
        if (lstat(currDirFile->d_name,&buf)<0){

            printf("lstat error");
            return 0;
        }

        /*If the st_mode(type) of the current file is regular
        we print the name of the file*/
        if (S_ISREG(buf.st_mode)){

                char *c = getFileNameExtension(currDirFile->d_name);

                if (c!=NULL){

                    //Check only for .txt files
                    if (strcmp(c,".txt")==0){

                        return 1;

                    }
                    else{

                        return 0;

                    }//End strcmp

                }//End c!=NULL

        }
        else{

           return 0;

        }//END S_ISREG


}

int countLines(struct dirent *currentFile){

    int fd = open(currentFile->d_name,O_RDONLY);
    int n;
    int lines = 0;
    char buf;

    while ((n=read(fd,&buf,1))>0){
        if (buf=='\n') ++lines;
    }

    return (lines);
}
```

I used the fork function in that way , but I'm not sure if it's correct, cause when I run it there are 4 father processes running(as I expected) but there are 3 more child processes running . Could anyone help me ? Actually , I'm trying to create a process for each text file .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial problem is that you have parent/child reversed.  When return from `fork` the child will have a `pid == 0` and the parent will be returned the pid of the child (that is, a positive non-zero number).  You are currently forking and immediately exiting the child and then printing out the wrong information.  When you do the `printf` the value of pid will be that of the child (returned in `fork`) not its own pid.  If you want the parent's pid then use `getpid`.  The child's printf, of course, will never print because it already exited and no longer exists.

Your other big problem is you need to keep in mind that children get a separate address space than the parent.  Although the child is initially a copy of the parent the two diverge over time and changes made by the child are *not* seen in parent.

Lastly, count and wait on your children.  It is not only a good practice but keeps your parent from exiting before all the children do.

**EDIT: Problem 1**

This is your first problem, see the numbered comments in the code

```
    while ( ( currDirFile = readdir(currentDir) ) != NULL )
    {
        if ( isTxtFile(currDirFile) == 1 )
        {
            if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
            {
                err_sys("fork error");
            }
            else
                if (pid == 0)      //(1) This is the child; it immediately dies
                {
                    exit(0);
                }
                else    //(2) Parent - it does ALL the work
                {
                    lines = realloc( lines , sizeof(int) * (counter + 1) );
                    lines[counter] = countLines(currDirFile);
                    ++counter;
                }
        }

        if (pid == 0)    //(3) This is reversed again which is why you think
        {                // you have multiple "fathers" when they are really children
            printf("Child , pid = %d\n", pid);
        }
        else
            printf ("Father , pid = %d\n", pid);
    } //End while
```

Output:

```
Father , pid = 17881
Father , pid = 17882
Father , pid = 17883
Father , pid = 17884
[nearly identical lines skipped]
114
14
7
3
128
12
```

So, making this correct we have:

```
printf ("Father pid = %d\n", getpid());  //(2b)

if (currentDir)
{
    while ( ( currDirFile = readdir(currentDir) ) != NULL )
    {
        if ( isTxtFile(currDirFile) == 1 )
        {
            if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
                err_sys("fork error");

            if (pid == 0)
            {
                //printf("Child pid = %d\n", pid);    // (1)
                printf("Child pid = %d\n", getpid());
                lines = realloc( lines , sizeof(int) * (counter + 1) );
                lines[counter] = countLines(currDirFile);
                ++counter;
                exit(0);
            }
        }

        //printf ("Father pid = %d\n", pid); //(2a)

    } //End while

    //close(currentDir);
}
```

(1) We don't print the value of `pid` in the child because it will *always* be zero. Rather we get the child's real pid value with `getpid()`.

(2) Keeping the parent `printf` in the loop (2a) will make it print every time through the loop regardless of whether it is text file or not, which is just annoying.  So we move it before the loop (2b) but because it is before the fork there won't be a valid value in `pid` so we just use `getpid()` to get that value as well.

So instead of

```
Father pid = 18136
Father pid = 18136
Father pid = 18136
[many identical lines]
Child pid = 0
Child pid = 0
Child pid = 0
```

we have the desired output of

```
Father pid = 18224
Child pid = 18225
Child pid = 18239
Child pid = 18240
[etc...]
```

Side note, for the purposes of compiling I assumed `err_sys` was something like this

```
void err_sys(const char *str)
{
    perror(str);
    exit(1);
}
```

**Problem 2**

You now have no output of the number of lines in a file.

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    printf("Child pid = %d\n", getpid());
    lines = realloc( lines , sizeof(int) * (counter + 1) );
    lines[counter] = countLines(currDirFile);
     ++counter;  //(1)
     exit(0);
}

for (i = 0;i < counter;++i)  //(2)
{
    printf("%d\n", lines[i]);
}
```

Because parent and child have separate memory, (1) the increments of `counter` will never be seen in parent.  Consquent (2) will be skipped over because it is zero and nothing prints.

So two options: (1) print from the child or (2) set up some IPC mechanism so the child reports its results back to parent so it can print them.  I'll proceed as if option 1 is the correct course of action.

We recognize some of this to be useless and make adjustments by (1) getting rid of the array - there will only be 1 value of line per child - and (2) moving the `printf` to where it will do some good.

```
//int *lines = malloc(sizeof(int));
int lines = 0;
//........

if (pid == 0)
{
    printf("Child pid = %d\n", getpid());
    //lines = realloc( lines , sizeof(int) * (counter + 1) );
    lines = countLines(currDirFile);
    //++counter;
    printf("%d\n",lines);
    exit(0);
}
```

This results in correct if ugly output:

```
Father pid = 18513
Child pid = 18514
114
Child pid = 18526
Child pid = 18527
4
7
```

So cleaning up the code and embellishing the output a bit we get

```
if (pid == 0)
{
    lines = countLines(currDirFile);
    printf("Child [%d] of parent [%d]: %s = %d lines\n",
            getpid(), getppid(), currDirFile->d_name, lines);
    exit(0);
}
```

And we see the output results in

```
Child [18566] of parent [18565]: output.txt = 114 lines
Child [18569] of parent [18565]: list.txt = 3 lines
Child [18574] of parent [18565]: bfile.txt = 9 lines
Child [18579] of parent [18565]: nums.txt = 4 lines
Child [18581] of parent [18565]: afile.txt = 9 lines
Child [18571] of parent [1]: output.txt = 12 lines
Child [18575] of parent [1]: cfile.txt = 18 lines
Child [18572] of parent [1]: alphabet.txt = 3 lines
```

Which is ok but the use of `getppid` in the `printf` shows us that the parent is ending before some of the children and they are getting inherited by the `init process` (pid = 1) after becoming orphaned.  So....

**Problem 3**

We need to prevent the race condition where the parent ends before the children and prevent making the children zombies.  This is what the `wait` and `waitpid` calls are for.  The wrinkle here is that if we place the `wait` in the loop the parent will block and wait for every child leading to one child running at a time.

```
    while ( ( currDirFile = readdir(currentDir) ) != NULL )
    {
        if ( isTxtFile(currDirFile) == 1 )
        {
            if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
                err_sys("fork error");

            if (pid == 0)
            {
                lines = countLines(currDirFile);
                printf("Child [%d] of parent [%d]: %s = %d lines\n",
                       getpid(), getppid(), currDirFile->d_name, lines);
                exit(0);
            }

            // ** this is the parent **
            if (wait(NULL) == -1)
                err_sys("wait");
        }
    } //End while
```

---

```
Child [18656] of parent [18655]: out.txt = 114 lines
Child [18657] of parent [18655]: input.txt = 7 lines
Child [18658] of parent [18655]: list.txt = 3 lines
Child [18659] of parent [18655]: output.txt = 12 lines
```

Since you want parallelism, one way to do it is to move the `wait` outside the loop and just count the children as you create them so they can be reaped later.

```
int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    DIR *currentDir;
    struct dirent *currDirFile;
    pid_t pid;
    int counter = 0;
    struct stat buf;

    int lines = 0;
    int numChildren = 0;

    currentDir = opendir(".");

    printf ("Father pid = %d\n", getpid());

    if (currentDir)
    {
        while ( ( currDirFile = readdir(currentDir) ) != NULL )
        {
            if ( isTxtFile(currDirFile) == 1 )
            {
                if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
                    err_sys("fork error");

                if (pid == 0)
                {
                    lines = countLines(currDirFile);
                    printf("Child [%d] of parent [%d]: %s = %d lines\n",
                           getpid(), getppid(), currDirFile->d_name, lines);
                    exit(0);
                }

                // ** this is the parent **
                numChildren++;
            }
        } //End while

        closedir(currentDir); // <-- note we use closedir not close for directories
    }

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < numChildren; ++i)
    {
        if ((pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, 0)) == -1)
            err_sys("fork error");
        else
            printf("parent [%d] reaped child [%d]\n", getpid(), pid);
    }

    exit(0);
}
```

Resulting in something like

```
Father pid = 18737
Child [18738] of parent [18737]: out.txt = 114 lines
Child [18741] of parent [18737]: list.txt = 3 lines
Child [18743] of parent [18737]: output.txt = 12 lines
Child [18747] of parent [18737]: cfile.txt = 18 lines
parent [18737] reaped child [18738]
parent [18737] reaped child [18741]
parent [18737] reaped child [18743]
Child [18754] of parent [18737]: append.txt = 6 lines
parent [18737] reaped child [18747]
parent [18737] reaped child [18754]
```

which is ugly but correct.  Since much of the output was just for demonstration you can pretty it up.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but could you explain better the last two lines ?  I did not understad if the problem is the output only

Comment: @IrishDog - I have update my answer on the assumption that you have finished most of this on your own anyway.

Comment: Ok, your solution was very sufficient and easy to understand . Thank you very much!